# My spiral grows too fast at the end and starts with a hole

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a spiral that changes color and grows bigger by itself. The problem is that it either starts with a hole or too dense too se the lines when I try to fix it. Another problem is that it grows too fast by the end so it looks bad, but too little in the beginning when I change it. The color systmem works just fine though.

How I want it too look like(with color):

[image: How I want it too look like(with color)]

How it looks:

[image: How it looks]

My code:

```
#inital startup
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
turtle.colormode(cmode=255)
z=0
j=1
v=0
a=0
b=0
c=0
x=4
g=True
t.speed(500)

#the spiral color loop
while g is True:

  t.forward(1)
  t.right(x)
  
   #makes the spiral grow
  x=x*0.999

 #the color system (nothing wrong here)
  t.pencolor(a ,b ,c)
  z=z+1
  if z>1019:
    z=0
  if 0<z<256:
    a=(a+1)
  if 254<z<510:
    a=(a-1)
  if 254<z<510:
    b=(b+1)
  if 509<z<765:
    b=(b-1)
  if 764<z<1020:
    c=(c+1)
    v=v+1 
  if v>254:
    c=(c-1)
  if c<1:
    v=1
```

Comment: See mathematics of [Archimidean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral).

Comment: Also, simple ideas at [turtle spirals](https://holypython.com/turtle-spirals/).

Comment: rather than altering the turn, you might try altering the forward. Perhaps by `+= 0.1` each loop with say a right of 10...

Answer (score 0):

Leaving your "color system" as is, I think you can start getting something more like you are after by altering the forward rather than the turn.

```py
#inital startup
import turtle

t=turtle.Turtle()
turtle.colormode(cmode=255)
z=0
j=1
v=0
a=0
b=0
c=0
g=True
t.speed(500)

forward_amt = 1
turn_amt = 10

#the spiral color loop
while g is True:

  forward_amt += 0.1
  t.forward(forward_amt)
  t.right(turn_amt)

  #the color system (nothing wrong here)
  t.pencolor(a ,b ,c)
  z=z+1
  if z>1019:
    z=0
  if 0<z<256:
    a=(a+1)
  if 254<z<510:
    a=(a-1)
  if 254<z<510:
    b=(b+1)
  if 509<z<765:
    b=(b-1)
  if 764<z<1020:
    c=(c+1)
    v=v+1 
  if v>254:
    c=(c-1)
  if c<1:
    v=1
```

After that, you can adjust `forward_amt` and/or `turn_amt` to your liking. As is, you should get:

[image: A Nice Spiral]